# Values not updating for dynamically added field in angular js

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I have created a form where fields are added dynamically.Adding works perfectly but the problem i am facing is when i am updating it.In the form there are two textboxes , a text area and a checkbox. Checkbox is checked depending upon the condition of a database field.At the time of editing all values are getting updated but the checkbox value is always getting set to true if i also unchecked the checkbox.

**Below the code i am using**

**The Json i am receiving**

```
$scope.choices = {"success":"yes","msg":"","data":{"checkListValues":[{"id":"81","checklist_id":"1","number":"1","short_text":"shorttext 12","long_text":"longtext12","is_photo":"1"},{"id":"82","checklist_id":"1","number":"2","short_text":"shorttext21","long_text":"longtext22","is_photo":"1"}]}}
```

**In the html Part**

```
<a ng-click="addNewChoice()" class="btn btn-success ng-scope" >Add More</a>

<tr data-ng-repeat="choice in choices track  by $index">
 <td>
    <div class="number-part">
    <input type="text" ng-model="choice.number" required />
    </div>
</td>
<td>
    <div class="shorttext-part">
    <input type="text" ng-model="choice.short_text" ng-trim="false" maxlength="40" required/>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <span class="character-count">{{40 - choice.short_text.length}} Characters left</span>

    </div>
</td>
<td>
<div class="shorttext-part">
<textarea ng-model="choice.long_text" ng-trim="false" maxlength="255" required></textarea>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<span class="character-count">{{255 - choice.long_text.length}} Characters left</span>
</div>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="checkbox"  ng-checked="choice.is_photo == 1" ng-model="choice.is_photo"/>
</td>
<td>
    <a ng-if="!$first"  ng-click="removeChoice($index)">
    <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
    </a>
</td>
```

**And In the angular js controller**

```
$scope.removeChoice = function(z)  
{
  var lastItem = $scope.choices.length-1;
  $scope.choices.splice(z,1);
};

$scope.addNewChoice = function() 
{
  var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length+1;
  $scope.choices.push({'id':'choice'+newItemNo});

     //console.log("=====",$scope.choices);
};
$scope.item = [];
var newItem = {};
for( var i in $scope.choices)
{
   newItem= $scope.choices[i];
   $scope.item.push(newItem);
}
```

So how to do that if  a checkbox is selected at the time of editing and if i unchecked it the value should be updated in the $scope.choices.
Working for the text box and text area... problem is happening only with the checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT Maybe it is better that is_photo to be a boolean, instead of string:
Than you dont need to use ngChange at all, you just need ng-model and ng-checked
I left in this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/mOEj3F9j6FT1HF1XEKWl?p=preview) ng-change so you can monitor the values of the checkbox models.

```
 <input type="checkbox"  ng-checked="choice.is_photo" ng-model="choice.is_photo" />
```

Comment: But it is not working on the first click to the checkbox .. why  ?

Comment: in the plunker you have set the value of is_photo in boolean .... but from the database it is returning 0 and 1 ....  so it is not working on the first time

Comment: Well it has to be a boolean, after frist click, if you check it ng-model="choice.is_photo" becomes true(instead of string "1") or if you uncheck it becomes false. There is no need to compare choice.is_photo with   "1"  after frist click because it is no longer a string. Sorry for this confussion with answers. If you get that object from db, go trough it and change all "1" to true and all "0" to false.Please ask if you have any more questions. Also try to log in the console onchage to see what is the value of the model after click.

Comment: @lignthe ... thanks buddy .. i have changed the values to boolean and it works